# Custom SportsPress list

Tags: plugins, php, customization, taxonomy

Im try to make a custom **[SportsPress](https://wordpress.org/plugins/sportspress/)** player list with PHP and I want to get all players from one team. But it doesn’t show any post, even not all players.

There’s the code:

```
<?php 
    $query = new WP_Query( array( 
        'post_type' => 'sp_player',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy'  => 'sp_team',
                'field'     => 'team',
                'terms'     => 197,
            )
        ),
    ) );                  

    if ( $query->have_posts() ) : ?>
        <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); 

        $staff = new SP_Staff( $post->ID );
        $current_teams = $staff->current_teams();

        foreach ( $current_teams as $team ):
            $team_name = sp_get_team_name( $team, $abbreviate_teams );
            if ( $link_teams ) $team_name = '<a href="' . get_post_permalink( $team ) . '">' . $team_name . '</a>';
            $teams[] = $team_name;
        endforeach;

    ?>   

            <?php the_title(); ?> ( <? echo $team_name; ?> ) - <?php the_date('d.m.Y', '', ''); ?>  <br/>

        <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

If I filter from post list at Admin dashboard it shows this link

```
http://www.example.com/wp-admin/edit.php?s
&post_status=all
&post_type=sp_player
&action=-1&m=201708
&tax_input%5Bsp_position%5D%5B0%5D=0
&tax_input%5Bsp_league%5D%5B0%5D=0
&tax_input%5Bsp_season%5D%5B0%5D=0
&team=197
&sp_season=2017
&filter_action=Filter
&paged=1
&action2=-1
```

And the post type slug for all teams ir `sp_team`

Answer (score 0):

`field` parameter of `tax_query` must be one of 'term_id', 'name', 'slug' or 'term_taxonomy_id'. In your case it will be 'term_id', which is also the default value.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters